# Advice about Designing SQL Database for catalog service for a marketplace

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, nosql, marketplace

I'm currently designing catalog service (SQL database), and I'm trying to combine SQL and NoSQL to store data like for "Data field form item table".

### Catalog service:

- Item_type table allows choosing different item types like simple, variable, digital...
- The attribute table has no direct relationship with the item table, but they are used to fill the attribute filed in the item table and store them as JSON.
- The Data field in the item table is a jsonb field, it's used to store data like variable products with their price, price relating quantity...
- RelatedStoreID is the store id from store service.

#### Questions:

1. is it good to store attributes in json field especially if these attributes are going to be used for indexing?
2. How can I improve the design?

[image]

Comment: Short version, don't.  Longer version, using JSON inside a field just hides the data structure and forces you to deal with it every time you unpack the data.  Make the structure explicit as tables and save yourself headaches down the road.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your great comment, JSON is a simple solution to avoid making a lot of JOINs.

Comment: No it isn't you still have to 'join' that information when you pull the ```JSON``` out and assign it to the table information. If you want to simplify the end ```SQL``` then build functions that return the data you need to the upper query.

Comment: Storing structured information in a JSON reduces the number of joins by a process called *denormalization*. However, joins are not a problem, relational databases are designed to perform joins efficiently. If you regularly need to access components of a JSON, want to use them in a `WHERE` or join condition or want to place constraints on them, you will find that it is either complicated or doesn't work efficiently at all.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks for your good analysis, but I'm planning to use the Postgres database and JSONB not JSON because it's supports indexing.

Comment: I was talking about JSON, although it applies to all composite data types. `jsonb` is affected as well. Yes, you can index it, so certain `WHERE` conditions will work ok, but cons and constraints will be painful.